# Screenshot IE7 Javascript

Tags: javascript, screenshot

I have tried but i can get this to work with IE7 or Firefox 5.0. I know that google.com/plus have a nice feedback that works in IE7.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

Is is using canvas but i have but plugins in all.

I get a error i first line of this code:

```
var preload = html2canvas.Preload(body, {
    "complete": function (images) {
        var queue = html2canvas.Parse(body, images);
        var canvas = $(html2canvas.Renderer(queue));
        var finishTime = new Date();
        $("#content").empty().append(canvas);
        //   throwMessage('Screenshot created in '+ ((finishTime.getTime()-timer)/1000) + " seconds<br />",4000);
    }
});
```

So if you have a zip file with a example that are working in IE7 or a example i will be more then happy.

Comment: It looks like it doesnt support IE.

Comment: Error: Function not supportet..

"Google is doing this in Google+ and a talented developer reverse engineered it and produced http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ . To work in IE you'll need a canvas support library such as http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/"

Comment: Google are doing a nice screenshot -function, so it can be done some how.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't support `<canvas>.`

So sorry :< but the browser is oooold

Comment: I can't opgrade the browser. Just got IE7 before IE6

This should make IE7 support Canvas: http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That's just a hack and not the real thing

Comment: I said IE7 does not support <canvas>. Was there something in the sentence which was unclear for you? :)

Comment: Your best bet would be using Google Chrome Frame plug-in: https://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Comment: Will i am not able to download anything on computers. I know you are right that IE7 do not support <canvas> but some how google use "flashcanvas". Do you have a idea to get this to work with "flashcanvas"?

Comment: <script src="jquery.js">//</script>
        <!--[if IE]><script src="excanvas.js">//</script><![endif]-->
        <script src="jquery.jqcanvas.js">//</script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("c1");  
        if (canvas.getContext) 
         { 
            var ctx = canvas.getContext ('2d');  
            ctx.fillRect (100,0,80,80);       // displays a full rectangle 
         }  
            });
        </script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="c1" width="400" height="100">Not implemented. 
   </ canvas>